# How do I SOQL Query this in Workbench?

Tags: soql, workbench

I can't figure out how to query ALL ACTIVE USERS AND THEIR PROFILE, THEIR PERMISSION SETS AND THEIR ROLES... please help!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you're getting any error messages, you should share them with us (just copy/paste the entire error). Please [edit] your question to add that information.

Comment: Also, please take some time to explain the bigger picture. This sounds like the solution to a problem/requirement. What is that problem/requirement? It could be that you're trying to go about this the hard way, see [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: There's no problem, my manager requested a list of all active users, the profile they have assigned to them, their permission sets and their role. I essentially figured it all out other than having it show the role name instead of the role id within the query I created so I just ran a separate query specifically for roles names and used V-lookup in excel :) I feel like I cheated but it got me what I needed. BTW the fact that every time I press enter to go to the next line and it posts my comment is annoying AF lol

Answer (score 0):

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT Name, UserName, UserRole.Name, Profile.Name, 
  (SELECT PermissionSet.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignments WHERE IsActive = true) 
FROM User WHERE IsActive = true
```

In Workbench:

```
/services/data/v58.0/query?q=SELECT+Name,+UserName,+UserRole.Name,+Profile.Name,+(SELECT+PermissionSet.Name+FROM+PermissionSetAssignments+WHERE+IsActive+=+true)+FROM+User+WHERE+IsActive+=+true
```

The output will look like:

```
{
  "totalSize": 1,
  "done": true,
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "User",
        "url": "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/User/005..."
      },
      "Name": "Brian Fear",
      "Username": "redacted@redacted.redacted",
      "UserRole": {
        "attributes": {
          "type": "UserRole",
          "url": "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/UserRole/00E..."
        },
        "Name": "CEO"
      },
      "Profile": {
        "attributes": {
          "type": "Profile",
          "url": "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/Profile/00e..."
        },
        "Name": "System Administrator"
      },
      "PermissionSetAssignments": {
        "totalSize": 1,
        "done": true,
        "records": [
          {
            "attributes": {
              "type": "PermissionSetAssignment",
              "url": "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/PermissionSetAssignment/0Pa..."
            },
            "PermissionSet": {
              "attributes": {
                "type": "PermissionSet",
                "url": "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/PermissionSet/0PS..."
              },
              "Name": "Audit_Fields"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If too many users or assignments are returned, you may need to follow the `nextURL` links (not shown here) to get the rest of the data.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked as a table query but I can't query it to view as a Bulk CSV... tell me "InvalidJob: Unable to find object: PermissionSetAssignments"

Comment: @DmitriyGerchikov You need to use JSON or XML format. CSV naturally does not support subqueries. When uploading the query, specify the correct content type, as mentioned in [Use Bulk Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_using_bulk_query.htm).